# The first fundamental theorem of calculus if the upper limit is a function.

Tags: calculus

Just curious.

If my function is
$$g(x,y) = \int_0^{x+y/4}f(t)\,dt$$
What is the partial derivative of the function w.r.t $x$?

Is it $f(x+y/4)$? What's the partial derivative of $y$ then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer to the first question is correct and as for the second question the answer is

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y} g (x, y) = \frac 1 4 f(x + y/4)$$

Take a look at [Leibniz formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule)!

Answer (score 3):

For partial derivatives of $$ g(x,y) = \int_0^{x+y/4}f(t)dt$$

You may apply the chain rule.

For example $$\frac {\partial }{\partial  y}\int_0^{x+y/4}f(t)dt= \frac {1}{4} f(x+y/4)$$

Answer (score 2):

Viewing the chain rule as differentiation by substitution often helps clarify:
\begin{align}
g & = \int_0^uf(t)\,dt \quad\text{and } u = x + \frac y 4 \\[10pt]
\frac{dg}{du} & = f(u) \quad \text{and } \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = \frac 1 4 \\[10pt]
f(u) \cdot \frac 1 4 & = f\left( x + \frac y 4 \right) \cdot \frac 1 4.
\end{align}